# What does it mean to make a content management system that is extendable?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

What am I extending exactly in a CMS when I write a module?  Is this the same as pluggable?  Thank you.

Comment: You are extenting a list of features. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is this (extendable) the same as pluggable?

Not quite, to me "pluggable" is an approach, a way of being extendable; so extendable is more wide ranging.

Pluggable infers that there is a well defined interface that others can build against. 
It's like a power socket - no matter where you take you device you should be able to plug it into the power mains (assuming your in the country!).

Pluggable also implies that you can swap one thing with another (as you'd expect), but also that you can do this with very little effort.

> > What am I extending exactly in a CMS when I write a module?

**Extenable** implies that you're add stuff, and that you're not removing or changing something that already exists.

So it means you're extending capability: usually related to functionality that users can use ("Look, you can now add blue **and** green widgets"), but might be more technical / not so user focused: you might extend a CMS system to allow authentication via [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) when previously it relied only on its local database; or send out emails when something happens rather than just log to a file.